# using the for loop and the split method only, I want to count how many IP address there is on the string called my_list

Tags: python, string, split, count

using the for loop and the split method only, I want to count how many IP address there is on the string called my_list.

```
  my_list = \
  '''
  inet addr :127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet addr :127.0.0.2 Mask:255.0.0.0

  inet addr :127.0.0.3 Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet addr :127.0.0.4 Mask:255.0.0.0
  '''

  count = 0
  for i in my_list : #this is the for loop but it returns 0 instead of 4
     if i == "127" :
       count = count + 1
  print(count)
```

I feel like I am missing something but I can't figure it out. Thank you for any help

Comment: is my_list a list of strings or a  single string in ''' quotes?

Comment: a single string

Comment: if you are iterating over a string, `i` will be a single character and will never be equal to `'127'`

Comment: so i would have to convert the string into a list for it to work?

Comment: The answer posted below works, do you need an answer just with for loop?

Comment: yes, I do need a way with a for loop

Comment: So, are you positive that all addresses are local and there are no other addresses?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer posted by qkzk works and is much simpler, but posting this because you want to use for loop.

```
my_list = \
  '''
  inet addr :127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet addr :127.0.0.2 Mask:255.0.0.0

  inet addr :127.0.0.3 Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet addr :127.0.0.4 Mask:255.0.0.0
  '''

# split the string at each end of line to convert it to a list of string
my_list_of_strings = my_list.split('\n')


count = 0
for string in my_list_of_strings: 
    if "127" in string : # check if '127' is in string 
        count = count + 1

print(count)
```

Output

```
4
```

Comment: Thank you, Kaushal!!! This makes so much sense now.

Comment: If you have a badly formed `inet addr`, say  `inet addr :127 Mask:255.0.0.0` - it would be counted as valid and will be recipe for future disasters if you have it in production. It is worrying that this is proposed as a solution (unless limitations/underlying assumptions are declared in advance) and, above all, that it is chosen as the best answer. But that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, `str` has a `count` method.

```
>>> my_list = \
...   '''
...   inet addr :127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
...   inet addr :127.0.0.2 Mask:255.0.0.0
... 
...   inet addr :127.0.0.3 Mask:255.0.0.0
...   inet addr :127.0.0.4 Mask:255.0.0.0
...   '''
>>> my_list.count('inet')
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the string every "inet" word and count the elements.

The count is off by one since split will create an empty string before the first occurrence of `"inet"`

```py
my_string = """ inet addr :127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet addr :127.0.0.2 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet addr :127.0.0.3 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet addr :127.0.0.4 Mask:255.0.0.0 
"""


count = len(my_string.strip().split("inet")) - 1

print(count)
```

When runned :

```
4
```

edit: as mentioned in previous comment, it's not a *list* but a *string*. Your `for` loop iterates over every character of that string. Since a character can't be `inet`, the condition is always `False` and the count isn't incremented.

Comment: I thought about that, but I wasn't sure if that is the right code for a for loop. would this answer be considered a for loop? Thanks for the quick response by the way.

Comment: Well, in the background, it's a for loop. `split` method iterates over the provided string using a for loop.
Now I don't know if it validates your consign.

Comment: Thank you for you help @qkzk. I am a new python student and I am getting confused using functions and loops. You answer help me understand another Simple way to get the result I wanted.